# ¿Cómo llamo una instancia de ArrayList desde otra clase?

Tags: java, array

Tengo una variable `ArrayList` en una clase y deseo instanciar este control para utilizarlo en otra clase. La variable es `ArrayList lst`. ¿Alguna idea de como realizar esta tarea?

```
List<TablaJira> lst = new ArrayList<>();
TablaJira ji = null;
for (int i = 1; i < firstSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    fila = firstSheet.getRow(i);
    ji = new TablaJira();
    ji.setFecha(fecha);
    for (int j = 0; j < fila.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        Cell celda = fila.getCell(j);
        if (j == 0) {
            if (celda == null || celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                break;
            }
        }
        switch (j) {
            case 0:
                if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    ji.setProyecto(celda.getStringCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    ji.setTipo(celda.getStringCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    ji.setClave(celda.getStringCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    ji.setTitulo(celda.getStringCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    ji.setNombres(celda.getStringCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    ji.setTiempo_horas((int) celda.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    if (ji.getNombres() != null) {
        lst.add(ji);
    }
}
Collections.sort(lst, TablaJira.comparet);
for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
    String nombre = lst.get(i).getNombres();
    if (nombre == null ? nombre_ant != null : !nombre.equals(nombre_ant)) {
        con = 1;
        lst.get(i).setPosicion(con);
        nombre_ant = nombre;
    } else {
        con++;
        lst.get(i).setPosicion(con);
    }
}
lst.forEach(ReadExcel2::guardarTblJira);
```

Comment: *Instanciar* significa crear una nueva instancia, un nuevo objeto que será independiente de las otras instancias que hayas creado. Se crean nuevas instancias con `new` + Constructor de la clase. Quizás lo que quieras sea *pasar/asignar una referencia* del objeto ya creado a otra instancia de otra clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos, como te indica el compañero, instanciar un objeto significa crear un nuevo objeto, es decir si es una lista, y la instancias utilizando la palabra reservada `new` en dos clases, estas serán completamente diferentes una de la otra. **Lo que te recomiendo** si deseas utilizar una lista conservando sus datos en diferentes clases es utilizar el patrón de diseño **Singleton**. Acá te dejo un ejemplo de como crearlo.

```
static List<TablaJira> lstSingleton;
 public static List<TablaJira> getlstSingleton {
        if(lstSingleton == null){
            lstSingleton = new List<TablaJira>();
        }
        return lstSingleton;
    }
```

Esta lista la podrás acceder desde cualquier clase utilizando el método getlstSingleton().

Espero que te sea de utilidad.